# Playwtight JS and QASE. How check the steps?

Tags: javascript, testing, plugins, report, playwright

I use plugin `playwright-qase-reporter`
Case contains some steps. How can I check it?

```
test.describe('Test suite', () => {

    test(qase(4, 'Several ids'), () => { // its case
        //here need check the step of test case
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    })
})
```

I read some info on git https://github.com/qase-tms/qase-javascript/issues/235
but didn't find any solution

Comment: I found only this thing
https://github.com/qase-tms/qase-javascript/pull/238/files
silent update..

but how I can use it?